# In React, is there a central function that gets called every time a render occurs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When we work with React, and especially app performance, we usually discuss renders.

Is there a central function that gets called every time a component renders?

e.g. `React.createElement()`?

If so, what is the path where this central function defined in the React repo? i.e. its exact file location. I couldn't find createElement in the repo on Github.

An idea I had was to add a counter to the central render function (e.g. createElement), and then I could print out the total number of renders that occurred when my app ran. It's a huge app with many child components, so a simple way of checking for optimisations is by checking how many renders occur. Unfortunately I do not have access to React Dev Tools.

Comment: Title sounds very poetic.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/cae635054e17a6f107a39d328649137b83f25972/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L355

Comment: what about document.createElement ? and, if this is the missing-link maybe there is a way to get what you are looking for from the OG document object (for measurement purposes).